# Regex Help in Parsing Syslog

Tags: regex, syslog

Firstly I am very new to regex and things like this just seem so complex and confusing to me, so if anyone has advanced resources I would love to see them.

I would like to split this with groups:

```
<189>: sample_username: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet2/0/1, changed state to down
```

And have these groups in return:

```
$1=sample_username
$2=LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN
$3=Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet2/0/1, changed state to down
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/jmu5i2/3) regex, along with the explanations.

```
<\d+>: (\w+): %([\w-]+): ([^\n]+)
```

The highlights are:

1. Parenthesis will capture what's inside them.
2. Brackets will match all the characters inside.
3. `[^x]` symbolizes "any character that is **not** `x`".
4. `x+` symbolizes any amount of `x`, bigger than zero.
5. `\w` and `\d` are [regex meta-characters](https://help.relativity.com/9.3/Content/Relativity/Regular_expressions/Regular_expression_metacharacters.htm). You can easily search more content about them.

Comment: Note `[\w_]` = `\w`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! Updated my answer